# Add new language string file dynamically for localisation in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, internationalization, mainbundle

**Approach**
I have implemented localization using string file as given below:
[image]
[image]

**Question**

**Is this possible to add new language file at runtime?**

Comment: @RajeshKumarR this is not I wanted. I want to add new language file as mentioned in above question.

Answer (score 1):

You can just create the proper bundle directories and strings files yourself and use the longer version of NSLocalizedString.

An [approach is described here](http://alejandromp.com/blog/2017/6/24/loading-translations-dynamically-generating-localized-string-runtime/) by Alejandro Martinez:

```
// The two important new parameters are `tableName` and `bundle`. 
// By default when using NSLocalizedString the system uses the App 
// main bundle and the Localizable table, *table* meaning the name 
// of the strings file. So to hook into the localization system we 
// just need to convert the object structure that we have in memory 
// to the proper file hierarchy that is expected on disk.
NSLocalizedString(_ key: String, tableName: String? = default, 
  bundle: Bundle = default, value: String = default, comment: String)
  -> String
```